# initializing char array with spaces

Tags: c++, c, string, char

I want a 20 character NULL('\0') terminating string filled with white spaces.

Currently I am doing it in following way

```
char foo[20];  
for (i = 0; i < num_space_req; i++)        //num_space_req < 20  
{  
    foo[i] = ' ';  
}

foo[num_space_req] = '\0';
```

Is there a better way for above?

Comment: `std::fill (foo, foo + num_space_req, ' ');`

Comment: Please try to avoid tagging questions with both C and C++ unless you _really_ need a cross-language solution. They are _vastly_ different languages once you remove all the legacy C stuff that C++ coders shouldn't be using anyway :-)

Comment: You've gotten a lot of good answers. You might want to accept one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::string foo(num_space_req,' ');
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use the following to initialize the array to spaces:

```
memset(foo, ' ', num_space_req);
foo[num_space_req] = '\0';
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but using memset wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: @bames53: Given that this question is tagged (amongst other things) as C, what would you choose?

Comment: Tagging questions with both C and C++ is usually a result of ignorance on the part of the asker, so I always take it to mean a C++ solution is acceptable. Otherwise they'd just tag it as C.

Answer (score 7):

Since the question has a C++ tag, the idiomatic way would be:

```
std::fill(foo, foo + num_space_req, ' ');
// or
std::fill_n(foo, num_space_req, ' ');
```

Note that it doesn't work in C.

Comment: good call bringing in the c++ idiom, but isn't this answer incomplete in that it doesn't place a null terminator?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `memset` for that kind of thing.

```
memset (foo, ' ', num_space_req)
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/

Answer (score 2):

As [@OliCharlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10384653/1119701) said, the best way is to use `memset`:

```
char bla[20];

memset(bla, ' ', sizeof bla - 1);
bla[sizeof bla - 1] = '\0';
```

Note that in GNU C, you can also use the following extension (range designated initializers):

```
char bla[20] = {[0 ... 18] = ' ', [19] = '\0'};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the array initialized at compile time, you can modify your char `foo[20];` declaration as follows:

`char foo[20] = {0x20};`

If you need to initialize the array to spaces at run time, then you can use the following:

```
memset(foo, ' ', sizeof(foo) -1);
foo[20] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

memset MIGHT be better optimised than your for loop, it might be exactly the same.
pick one of:

```
memset( foo, ' ', sizeof(foo) -1 );
memset( foo, ' ', 19 );
memset( foo, ' ', 19 * sizeof(char) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstring>
void makespace(char *foo, size_t size) {
  memset((void*)&foo, ' ', size - 1);
  foo[size] = 0;
}
// ...
makespace(foo, 20);
```